# Android studio project is messed up due to moving files around

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to create new packages to organize the java folder but then I moved them out of the new package. Now I am having issues.

`MainActivity` is not being recognized in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

The files are now green colored?

How can I restore the files to working condition, any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing a Gradle sync in Tools>Android.

Otherwise, copy your Activities back to where they were before you moved them. Then move them using the Refactor menu (Right-click on your java class, go to Refactor submenu and hit move).

Answer (score 0):

Manifest folder should not be marked as source root 
right click on manifest folder ->mark directory as -> Unmark...

Comment: Thanks but I dont see that option when I right click it